# Singular Vs plural- Visit again and get a 20% discount on a/any beverage?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I saw a sentence written on some pamphlet of a restaurant and the sentence was like this:

> 1. "Visit again and get a 20% discount on a beverage."
> 2. "Visit again and get a 20% discount on beverages."

First question is what's the difference between the two sentences?

I am attaching a link [**here**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a) and request you to go through RegDwight's answer. He says in many cases where the indefinite article, ***a***, is used we can replace it by ***any***.

Based on his suggestion now look at the sentence 2 again:

> 3. "Visit again and get a 20% discount on (a=)any beverage".

You see, now this sentence (3)  where I have used ***any*** in place of ***a*** sounds okay to me. But if I read the sentence (1) with ***a***, then it doesn't sound that okay. Why is it so?

Comment: 2 sounds like you would get 20% off **all** drinks on your next visit

Comment: *Get a discount on a beverage...* grammatically leaves a doubt as to whether it applies to ALL beverages. But *Get a discount on any beverage* or *...on beverages* suggests that the discount is available on all of them.

Comment: Neither of these sentences is sufficiently precise to know exactly what is meant.  All we know is that the discount applies to what you can order to drink, not to what you eat.  It might as well say "Ask your server for details".

Comment: @WS2 : Well you say sentence (1) leaves a doubt. But if you go through RegDwight's answer he says we can substitute 'any' in place of 'a'. So by that logic this sentence 1 should be correct. Am i missing something ?

Comment: @Brock: the answer in the link you've cited opens with a caveat: "If you insist on the rule being simple..."  You should understand that to mean that what he says might apply most of the time, but not all of the time.  **a** is not always interchangeable with **any**. It depends on context. There is no guarantee that you would get 20% discount on their top-shelf brandy, say.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes - well put.

Comment: Okay let me give a sentence with a context. Suppose I am working on some initiative and if someone asks what this initiative all about and I reply : 

1) "This initiative tries to help 'a student' realise his true potential so that he doesn't face any problem in future".

1') "This initiative tries to help 'students' realise their true potential so that they do not face any problem in future."

What's the difference between these two sentences ?

Answer (score 1):

It mainly differentiates in what the discount applies to.  The versions all suggest different quantities of beverages as well as different variations.

> 1. "Visit again and get a 20% discount on a beverage."

This sounds like visiting again will result in a discount on a *specific* beverage, though it could also be read as any beverage.  It's unclear exactly what it's applying to, but we do know it's referring to a *singular* beverage, unlike the next sentence.

> 2. "Visit again and get a 20% discount on beverages."

This sounds like it is a blanket discount on all beverages, i,e. if i were to purchase forty cokes, i'd get 20% off on all of them; additionally, if i were to purchase a coke and a sprite and a pepsi and a fanta, i'd get 20% on all of those too.  So this one is unambiguously referring to any beverage, as well as more than one.

> 3. "Visit again and get a 20% discount on any beverage."

This is a clearer, more specific version of the first sentence.  We know the discount applies to *one* soda, and it can truly be *any* soda, not a specific one.